# Show the name of order comment author in Magento Sales Order View

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

I have created a custom module to allow for order comments to be submitted on Magento frontend
Sales_Guest_View

I am able to show the name of the author of the comment on the Frontend but I also need the name to show in the Admin panel in Sales_Order_View.

The reason is to keep track of order comments etc in Magento Admin.

Here is the frontend controller for the form which shows Authors Name

```
<?php

require_once Mage::getModuleDir('Controller', 'Mage_Sales') . DS . 'Controller' . DS . 'Abstract.php';

class Tamedo_FrontendOrderMessage_FormController extends Mage_Sales_Controller_Abstract {

    protected $_guest_cookieName  = 'guest-view';
    protected $_guest_lifeTime    = 600;

    public function orderAction() {
        if(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()) {
            $this->_loadValidOrder();
        } else {
            Mage::helper('sales/guest')->loadValidOrder();
        }
        $order = Mage::registry('current_order');
        $orderId = $order->getId();
        if(empty($orderId)) {
            if (Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()) {
                $this->_redirect('sales/order/history');
            } else {
                $this->_redirect('sales/guest/form');
            }
        } else {
            $data = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
            if (!empty($data['history']['comment']))
                $append = " Posted By: ".$username.""; {
                $order->addStatusHistoryComment($data['history']['comment'], false)
                        ->setIsVisibleOnFront(true)
                        ->setIsCustomerNotified(false);
                $order->save();
            }
            if (Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()) {
                $this->_redirect('sales/order/view', array('order_id' => $order->getId()));
            } else {
                $toCookie = base64_encode($order->getProtectCode());
                Mage::getSingleton('core/cookie')->set($this->_guest_cookieName, $toCookie, $this->_guest_lifeTime, '/');
                $this->_redirect('sales/guest/view');
            }
        }
    }

}
```

And the Admin Controller which only shows the name of the Admin that submitted the comment

```
<?php
/**
 * Tamedo
 *
 * NOTICE OF LICENSE
 *
 * This source file is subject to the Open Software License (OSL 3.0)
 * that is bundled with this package in the file LICENSE.txt.
 * It is also available through the world-wide-web at this URL:
 * http://opensource.org/licenses/osl-3.0.php
 * If you did not receive a copy of the license and are unable to
 * obtain it through the world-wide-web, please send an email
 * to license@magentocommerce.com so we can send you a copy immediately.
 *
 * @category    Atwix
 * @package     Atwix_OrderComment
 * @author      Atwix Core Team
 * @copyright   Copyright (c) 2012 Atwix (http://www.atwix.com)
 * @license     http://opensource.org/licenses/osl-3.0.php  Open Software License (OSL 3.0)
 */
require_once 'Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/OrderController.php';
class Tamedo_OrderComment_Adminhtml_Sales_OrderController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Sales_OrderController
{
    /**
     * Add order comment action
     */
    public function addCommentAction()
    {
        if ($order = $this->_initOrder()) {
            try {
                $response = false;
                 //getting username
                $user = Mage::getSingleton('admin/session');
                $username = $user->getUser()->getUsername();
                $append = " posted by: ".$username."";
                $data = $this->getRequest()->getPost('history');
                $notify = isset($data['is_customer_notified']) ? $data['is_customer_notified'] : false;
                $visible = isset($data['is_visible_on_front']) ? $data['is_visible_on_front'] : false;


                //appending username with markup to comment
                $order->addStatusHistoryComment($data['comment'].$append, $data['status'])
                    ->setIsVisibleOnFront($visible)
                    ->setIsCustomerNotified($notify);

                $comment = trim(strip_tags($data['comment']));

                $order->save();
                $order->sendOrderUpdateEmail($notify, $comment);

                $this->loadLayout('empty');
                $this->renderLayout();
            }
            catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
                $response = array(
                    'error'     => true,
                    'message'   => $e->getMessage(),
                );
            }
            catch (Exception $e) {
                $response = array(
                    'error'     => true,
                    'message'   => $this->__('Cannot add order history.')
                );
            }
            if (is_array($response)) {
                $response = Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($response);
                $this->getResponse()->setBody($response);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Does anyone know how I can include the Frontend Authors name in the back or where I need to amend my code. I have attempted but keep resulting in an error..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure what you are trying to do, but you could try to use the order billing or shipping name for the username or get current log in user info.

To get Customer name from session

```
$username = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer()->getName()
```

To get Customer information from order

```
$username = $order->getCustomerFirstname() . ' ' . $order->getCustomerLastname()
```

Then update your code to

```
.....
if (!empty($data['history']['comment']))
    $comment = $data['history']['comment'] . " Posted By: {$username}."; {
    $order->addStatusHistoryComment($comment, false)
          ->setIsVisibleOnFront(true)
          ->setIsCustomerNotified(false);
    $order->save();
 }
```

Comment: Basically, I've built a callcentre application for Magento which uses a a similar frontend layout and template structure for placing orders. The only difference being that CallCenter agents have to login to the website the place orders over the phone. If an agent adds a comment I will need it to reflect in Magento admin as customer services team will need to keep a track of order history just in case a customer calls up to complain...